# Extract json from mixed content string

Tags: php

I have an string of mixed content, something like:

> {json stuff} Other content from same output has < html > tags like
>   < div >some< / div > and more stuff, at the end it has another {json stuff}

So what I need is to be able to use those 3 elements:
So to get the first json I do this:

```
$first_json = json_decode(substr($mixed_string,0, strpos($mixed_string,"}")+1 ));
// that will get me the first json content
// Then I need the second json which is at the end of the string, 
// the length of the string is unknown , the json length is unknown
// after that I just do:
echo preg_replace("/\{[^)]+\}/","",$mixed_string);
// and I get the html from that string...
```

So, how can I get the last json?

Comment: use `strrpos` to find the last `{` in the string, then substr from there to the end?

Comment: @MarcB Won't work on `{"a":"b"} <random garbage> {"a":{"b":"c"}}`.

Comment: @Siguza: of course not, which makes the proper answer "fix whatever's spitting out this garbage so it outputs PROPER json".

Comment: Plus, what if the json is just an integer? `json_encode(42) -> 42`. can't tell that if that's a json 42 or part of the phrase, e.g. `42 is the answer to life the universe and everything {"foo":"bar"}` would also be `json stuff json`. basically: garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @MarcB I wish i knew who build it, I have no access, i have requested access to that script to that I can fix the output, after a week I give up asking and now I'm stuck with that, delivery time is running out so i have to make it work some how... I wonder who downvoted me and if that person care to explain why...

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to grab the JSON values, and it'll let you grab the JSON out of any string, no matter the length. Let's say you have a `div` with an ID of content, and that `div` has JSON you want to extract:

**EDIT:** Added the extraction process as a function.

```js
function extractJSON(content) {
  var regex = /({.*?})/g,
    raw = content.match(regex),
    output = [],
    errors = [];

  raw.forEach(function(el) {
    try {
      output.push(JSON.parse(el));
    } catch (e) {
      errors.push('issue with object: ' + el);
    }
  });

  return {
    results: output,
    errors: errors
  }
}

// Grab the elements that contain JSON
var elements = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;

console.log(extractJSON(elements));
```